# how to make modal cover entire screen and be web-responsive at the same time?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I want my modal to be in the centre of the screen, take up the whole screen, whether it be on a laptop or phone eg ios, android but I simply cannot get it to work. I also want to get rid of the red highlight around it but have no idea how. I want to style the "hide modal" button as well so that it can appear as a small cross in the right hand side. any suggestions are appreciated.  https://ibb.co/qB4jVVc

```
<View style = {styles.modal}>
                <Modal
                  visible={modalVisible}
                  transparent = {true}
                  onRequestClose={() => {
                    Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
                  }}
                >
                  <View style = {styles.container}>
                      <Text>Dear Customer, you have successfully paid for your trip from {startingLocation} to {endingLocation},
                       scheduled at {departure}{timeFormat}. Your receipt number is {Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000)}
                      </Text>
          
                        <TouchableHighlight
                          onPress={() => {
                            setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
                          }}
                        >
                          <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                  </View>
                </Modal>
              </View>

 modal : {

    backgroundColor:    "rgb(232,232,232)",
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the modal to cover the whole screen, try the following snippet,

```
<Modal
  style={{ margin: 0 }}>
  <View
     style={{ height: hp("100%"), width: wp("100%"), flex: 1 }}>
     ......write you layout here
  </View>
</Modal>
```

Note: for hp and wp - refer this [react-native-responsive-screen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-screen)

Revert back to me, if you need more details.

Comment: thanks so much. I just have another query. I have a React-Native picker that is not mobile-responsive, for some reason the picker outline gets cut off when on mobile and I have no idea why - what styling property do I have to change to fix this : https://ibb.co/JnmyJZV

Comment: So you have other pickers for the ending station and time. Those are fine. is it? then something problem with styling. can you please share some code snippet to get more details?
By the way, the modal answer is useful, then please mark it as accepted and useful.